# creating properties in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm going thru a tutorial and the author creates the properties of a class in the constructor.  Is there a reason to do it this way instead of creating the properties in the class itself?

My background is C# so the reason why I would pass a parameter in the constructor is to make sure that when the class is instantiated, the arguments in the constructor are passed.

Here is the code that the author wrote:

```
export class Exercise {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public title: string,
        public description: string,
        public image: string,
        public nameSound?: string,
        public procedure?: string,
        public videos?: Array<string>
    ) {

    }
}
```

This is the way that I create the class:

```
export class Exercise {

    public name: string,
    public title: string,
    public description: string,
    public image: string,
    public nameSound?: string,
    public procedure?: string,
    public videos?: Array<string>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining parameters in the constructor with the access modifier (`public`, `private`, `protected`) allows you to assign values during the class' instantiation.

```
class MyConvenientClass {
  constructor(public myProp: string) {}
}
const myInstance = new MyConvenientClass('someValue')
```

If you only declare those properties, you'll have to assign them later which is not that convenient.

```
class MyMundaneClass {
  public myProp: string
}
const myInstance = new MyMundaneClass()
myInstance.myProp = 'someValue'
```

There's also one more difference. If you set the `strictPropertyInitialization` flag in the TS config, then you'll have to change the `myProp` typing in the `MyMundaneClass` to `string | undefined`. This is because TS can't tell for sure the value will always be there and hence requires you to explicitly state this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the attributes in the constructor, for example:

```
constructor (public x: string) {
}
```

It is the same thing of:

```
public x: string;
constructor (x: string) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

So, you just do the same thing, but writing a little bit less.